# what could be the best way to work with images in android specially images that are sent via api?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've developed a billing app that syncs items locally using a Room database for fast retrieval. Now, my client is interested in displaying images alongside the items, which are uploaded from a web domain.

Currently, I've stored image raw data in the Room database and decoded it into bitmaps to display in the views. While this approach generally works well, I'm encountering occasional Out of Memory (OOM) exceptions.

How can I efficiently manage images to avoid OOM issues while ensuring smooth integration of images from the web domain? Are there any best practices or libraries that can help with memory optimization when dealing with images in Android?

Comment: Always use uri for storing/retrieving images

Comment: @Vivek Gupta, please explain how that would go. And explain how that would prevent OOM errors.

Comment: Instead of storing raw image data, you store the path of the image in room database. OOM exceptions occurs when you try to load big images, you can use third party libraries like Glide, picasso  etc to load images in the app efficiently.